# Imagen dentro de tabla responsive con bootstrap sale alargada

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Estoy tratando de que se vea una imagen bien dentro de una tabla en responsive. He tratado con varias clases de bootstrap para imagenes en responsive pero sigue saliendo alargada.

Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal.

Este es mi codigo :

```
<div style="margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;" class="table-responsive"><tdead></tdead><table id="tbUser" cellpadding="10" align="center" class="table-responsive-xxl table-bordered border-primary"><tbody><tr class="text-center"><td class="text-center">Ref</td><td class="text-center" style="width:300px">Foto</td><td>Talla/Color</td><td>Cantidad Disponible</td><td class="text-center">Gramos</td><td class="text-center">Unidades</td><td class="text-center">Precio : <div onchange="changeprecioG(1, this);"><input type="text" size="4" name="GPrecio" value="" id="GPrecio"></div></td><td class="text-center">Valor Total</td><td class="text-center">Observaciones</td><td class="text-center">Eliminar</td></tr><tr align="center"><td align="center">ARPY6-21</td><td style="width:30%"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://decolombiajoyas.com/joyeriaoroplata/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/DSC_0149-2.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></td><td>blanco</td><td>1</td><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="Peso265" id="Peso" value="6.6">6.6 grs</td><td align="center">
    <script>
    function sumar265(){
    var Peso = $('input[name="Peso265"]').val();
    var Cantidad = $('input[data-inputtype="Cantidad265"]').val();
    //var Cantidad = $('[data-inputtype="Cantidad265"]').val($(this).val());
    var Precio = $('input[id="Precio265"]').val();
    var total = Peso * Cantidad * Precio;
    var n = '$'+total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1.');  // 12,345.67
    
    $('.result265').html(n);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
    sumar265();
    });
    </script><br><div onchange="ccantu(265, this);"><input max="1" id="num265" size="2" 
 onkeyup="sumar265(); GFG_Fun265();" type="text" data-inputtype="Cantidad265" 
 name="CantidadI[]" placeholder="0" required=""> <br> <p id="GFG_DOWN265" style="color: 
 green;"></p></div><br></td><td><div onchange="changeprecio(265, this);"><input type="text" 
 class="Precio" placeholder="" value="" size="4" name="Precio[]" id="Precio265" data- 
 inputtype="Precio" onkeyup="sumar265()"></div></td><td><b><div class="result265" 
 id="result265">$0.00</div></b></td><td><div onchange="obs(265, this);"><textarea 
 id="Observaciones[]" name="Observaciones[]" cols="20" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea> 
 </div><input type="hidden" id="id" name="idpedido[]" value="265"> </td><td><button 
 onclick="window.open(&quot;https://wx.decolombiajoyas.com/eliminaproducto.php? 
 idpedido=265&quot;, &quot;theFrame&quot;, &quot;width=50,height=50&quot;);" 
 class="btnDelete">X</button></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Escencial va esté codigo en la imagen y la table :

TABLA : `<div align='center'><input type='button' value='Terminar Pedido' onClick='submitDetailsForm()' /></div><div style='margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;' class='table-responsive' ><table id='tbUser' cellpadding='10' align='center' class='table-responsive-xxl table-bordered border-primary'><tdead><tr class='text-center'><td class='text-center'>Ref</td><td class='text-center' style='width:300px'>Foto</td><td>Talla/Color</td><td>Cantidad Disponible</td><td class='text-center'>Gramos</td><td class='text-center'>Unidades</td>";`

IMAGEN : `<img class='img-responsive' src='$ProductoURL' style='width: 300px; height: 300px;'>";`

Como sale :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias amigos por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que la imagen se ajuste correctamente, agregar el style que muestro acontinuación:

```
style="width: 100%; min-width: 70px; min-height: 70px; height: auto;"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;" class="table-responsive"><tdead></tdead><table id="tbUser" cellpadding="10" align="center" class="table-responsive-xxl table-bordered border-primary"><tbody><tr class="text-center"><td class="text-center">Ref</td><td class="text-center" style="width:300px">Foto</td><td>Talla/Color</td><td>Cantidad Disponible</td><td class="text-center">Gramos</td><td class="text-center">Unidades</td><td class="text-center">Precio : <div onchange="changeprecioG(1, this);"><input type="text" size="4" name="GPrecio" value="" id="GPrecio"></div></td><td class="text-center">Valor Total</td><td class="text-center">Observaciones</td><td class="text-center">Eliminar</td></tr><tr align="center"><td align="center">ARPY6-21</td><td style="width:30%">

<img  style="width: 100%; min-width: 70px; min-height: 70px; height: auto;" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" >
</td><td>blanco</td><td>1</td><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="Peso265" id="Peso" value="6.6">6.6 grs</td><td align="center">
    <script>
    function sumar265(){
    var Peso = $('input[name="Peso265"]').val();
    var Cantidad = $('input[data-inputtype="Cantidad265"]').val();
    //var Cantidad = $('[data-inputtype="Cantidad265"]').val($(this).val());
    var Precio = $('input[id="Precio265"]').val();
    var total = Peso * Cantidad * Precio;
    var n = '$'+total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1.');  // 12,345.67
    
    $('.result265').html(n);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
    sumar265();
    });
    </script><br><div onchange="ccantu(265, this);"><input max="1" id="num265" size="2" 
 onkeyup="sumar265(); GFG_Fun265();" type="text" data-inputtype="Cantidad265" 
 name="CantidadI[]" placeholder="0" required=""> <br> <p id="GFG_DOWN265" style="color: 
 green;"></p></div><br></td><td><div onchange="changeprecio(265, this);"><input type="text" 
 class="Precio" placeholder="" value="" size="4" name="Precio[]" id="Precio265" data- 
 inputtype="Precio" onkeyup="sumar265()"></div></td><td><b><div class="result265" 
 id="result265">$0.00</div></b></td><td><div onchange="obs(265, this);"><textarea 
 id="Observaciones[]" name="Observaciones[]" cols="20" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea> 
 </div><input type="hidden" id="id" name="idpedido[]" value="265"> </td><td><button 
 onclick="window.open(&quot;https://wx.decolombiajoyas.com/eliminaproducto.php? 
 idpedido=265&quot;, &quot;theFrame&quot;, &quot;width=50,height=50&quot;);" 
 class="btnDelete">X</button></td></tr></tbody></table></div>

</body>
</html>
```